# animation gets laggy after creating many objects dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, after creating ~400 `ImageView` instance (by calling `updateUI(NewImage)` ~400 times) the newly created `ImageView` animation would be laggy, the more time elapsed the more laggy they become. I think after an`ImageView` animation is done, i must destroy them to avoid being laggy. any idea?

```
public  void updateUI(final Bitmap bitmap)
   {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final ImageView tmp = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            tmp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            tmp.setY(AT_THE_BOTTON_OF_ACTIVITY);
            rv.addView(tmp); add the ImageView to the Relalayout
           tmp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                    //disappear the imageView
                    ImageView t=imgs.get(id);
                    ObjectAnimator opacity = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tmp(The ImageView), "alpha", 0.0f);
                    opacity.setDuration(200);
                    opacity.start();

               }
           });

            ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tmp, "y", 0);
            anim2.setDuration(5000);
            anim2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim2.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't show 400 imageViews on a screen can you?Is it 400 inches?Lol.That's why recyclerView was implemented.Try to use recyclerView and add your items there.The whole idea is the views that you don't see are destroyed and the ones are there are also recycled and not made from begging each time.And then you can put your animations on the only visible items to the user.

Comment: at a moment maybe ~20 ImageView are shown in the activity not all of ~400. there are animation on the objects (from botton to top of the activity) . ~4 imageView per sec are created. any way you think it's better to use recyclerView ?

Comment: Without a doubt use recyclerView.You shouldn't handle 400 layouts.It can be so hard you should know which view is there which isn't and do a lot of things...